# Get All users related Data mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I need to get all data related to the user table from all other tables

so if I have a user table and posts, comments, ... etc, I would get in any shape all of his data combined so I can extract them into .sql file

what I have got so far is

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name' 
AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'user';
```

this returns all the tables that contain a foreign key of the user Id

```
SELECT * 
FROM `posts` 
WHERE userId in (
            SELECT id 
            FROM `user` 
            WHERE name like "%test%");
```

this returns all of the data from 1 table related to a group of users that contains "test" in their names

My question is how to combine those 2 together
or if you have a better solution

Comment: use joins to combine two or more tables.

Comment: https://www.tutsmake.com/mysql-inner-left-right-joins-for-beginners/

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki  what 2 tables to join?? <br>
the result of the first query is 'tables' <br> there is nothing to join them on

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles same question

Comment: "there is nothing to join them on" Is there a common key in the various tables? Does `posts.userId` correspond to `user.id` ? If so, `SELECT * FROM user JOIN posts ON user.id = post.userId`. If you don't actually have common keys in the tables, and you don't have a linking table, you can't `JOIN` them.

Comment: If you are querying information schema database then you will get users information from different databases present in your mysql instance. There is no way you can join two or more tables from different databases unless the mysql user has permission to query all the databases.